# In Mockswitch is there a way to temporarily disable a case?

Tags: rest, mocking, mockswitch

I understand with [Mockswitch](https://mockswitch.com) we can create multiple cases which are executed by sequentially top down but if I have to temporarily disable a case if that possible so that it goes to the next case ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable a case simply by deactivating case of right hand corner of the case details.

[image]